# Displaying .aspx and .aspx.cs files such that it's not understood by the browser

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

I have to give the user the option to upload his own aspx and aspx.cs files on to the server,
and adjusting the hyperlink to point to a page which would do the following.

Display the aspx and aspx.cs files code onto the page without actually rendering the code.

The browser should not understand anything and
while reading the files to display them the method be such that nothing is processed on the server regarding the code within the files to prevent from unnecessary problems many users would try to cause.

I have tried many ways of displaying it but it ends up on displaying the actual comments instead of the code.

Please note main concentration is on ASP.NET and C# using Visual Studio 2008, so JavaScript and ready-made tools should be avoided if feasible.

Comment: Please be advised that that is a massive security issue. You are actually given the user full access to your computer. I assume even if you limit the privileges of the assembly executing that code, there will still be a way to gain full access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the MIME type to `text/plain`.

Comment: or, alternatively, create a text box, create a string from the file contents, and set the text box text to the string

Comment: forgive th ignorance but how to you set mime type? there is nothing like that in labels or any controls properties

Comment: You set the mime type using Response.ContentType